# How to Send form using AJAX with Recaptcha? [Laravel]

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

how can I send my form using AJAX with recaptcha? I'm currently using the package from anhskohbo/no-captcha.

SignupController.php

```
  public function customRegister(Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => ['required', 'max:52'],
        'phone_number' => ['required', 'unique:users', 'min:11', 'max:11'],
        'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', 
        Password::min(8)
        ->mixedCase()
        ->symbols()
        ->numbers()
        ],
        'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required', 'captcha'],
    ]);

    if(!$validator->passes()) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 0, 'error'=> $validator->errors()->toArray()]);
    } else {

        User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number'),
        'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
        'is_verified' => 0,

        ]);
}
```

Form.blade

```
        <form action="/register" id="registerForm" method="POST">
        @csrf
        ... form inputs here
<div class="form-group fxt-transformY-50 fxt-transition-delay-5">
                                    <div class="{{ $errors->has('g-recaptcha-response') ? ' has-error' : '' }} recaptcha-div">
                                        {!! NoCaptcha::display() !!}
                                        <span class="text-danger error-text g-recaptcha-response_error"></span>
                                    </div>                        
                                </div>
        </form>
```

My Ajax function

```
    $(function(){
              
    $("#registerForm").on('submit', function(e){       
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var token = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        $.ajax({
            url:$(this).attr('action'),
            method:$(this).attr('method'),
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData:false,
            dataType:'json',
            contentType:false,
            beforeSend:function(){
                $(document).find('span.error-text').text('');
                FormData.append('recaptcha', token);
            },
            success:function(data){
                if(data.status == 0){                            
                    $.each(data.error, function(prefix, val){
                        $('span.'+prefix+'_error').text(val[0]);
                    });
                }else{
                    $('#registerForm')[0].reset();
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I always get the following error 'recaptcha is required'. It seems that the formData is not getting the recaptcha value.  Can anyone give me advice? Thank you!

Comment: what are you using to show your recaptcha

Comment: Hello @bhucho I'm using the Anshkobo/no-captcha package. I updated the code above. Thank you so much

Comment: why do you want to send it via ajax, do you want a recaptcha to be not shown?

Comment: If you are actually submitting a form via js then why not use the google recaptcha library directly there is no need for a backend package then

Answer (score 3):

**How it work for me**

In form

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{config('services.recaptcha.key')}}"></div>
```

Script recaptcha

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Ajax function

```
$("#registerForm").on('submit', function(e){       
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var gtoken = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: {
                g_recaptcha_response: gtoken,
            },
```

In validation request

```
'g_recaptcha_response' => 'required|recaptcha'
```